How to host typescript on render
I am looking for a documentation to help me host typeScript on render
I tried using the documentation on there official website, where they used CRA but it's throwing errors in my package.json fileenter image description here

What does "host typescript on render" mean? Also please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
